# How to add a created element in the CRM section using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I want to add a created element in JS into CRM form. How could I do it and is it possible?

```
var body = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("Tab").sections.get("Section");
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
body.appendChild(tbl); // I need to add created tbl into CRM section but feiling here
```

Comment: Your question is very incomplete! What is XRM, what do you want to achieve? ...

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are trying is unsupported in Xrm context. Instead it’s recommended to build a custom HTML web resource, build the table there.

The web resource can be embedded in the Xrm entity form section. This is totally supported.

[HTML webresource in CRM](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/extending-crm/javascript/html-web-resources/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But then the question is if i can manipulate with the CRM fields from HTML web resource file, because i want to build the table based on CustomAcion output result.

Comment: @ViktorijaBlaziene yes you can. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/hardworkdays/archive/2015/02/28/howto-html-js-webresources